# Send png via packet from server to client: indexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, netty, packet

I am getting an indexOutOfBoundException using netty when trying to send over a png from server to client. The error occurs on the line where it reads the bytes `p.readBytes()` in client.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(97) + length(199852) exceeds writerIndex(185453): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 97, widx: 185453, cap: 185453)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1395)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1389)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:850)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:858)
    at com.benberi.cadesim.client.codec.util.Packet.readBytes(Packet.java:79)
    at com.benberi.cadesim.client.packet.in.ListAllMapsPacket.execute(ListAllMapsPacket.java:29)
```

Server Side:

1. Get images in a specific folder where the server is located
2. Convert image to a byte array for sending data
3. Send data to the client using packet

Client-Side:

1. Receive byte array of image // issue occurs here I believe
2. Convert byte array to Pixmap (libgdx)
3. Add pixmap to a specific index of Pixmap array
4. Do something with pixmap later

Server Packet:

```
    @Override
    public void encode() {
        setPacketLengthType(PacketLength.MEDIUM); //
        writeByte((byte)ServerConfiguration.getAvailableMaps().size());
        for (int i=0; i<ServerConfiguration.getAvailableMaps().size(); i++)
        {
            String map = ServerConfiguration.getAvailableMaps().get(i).replace(".txt", "");
            writeByteString(map);
            String mapDir = String.format("maps/%s.png", map);
            try {
                File imageFile = new File(mapDir);
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
                writeInt((int)imageFile.length()); //write size of image
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", stream);
                writeBytes(stream.toByteArray()); // write image; byte array
                stream.flush();
                stream = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
//              e.printStackTrace();
                writeInt(0);
            }
        }
        setLength(getBuffer().readableBytes());
    }
```

Client Packet:

```
    @Override
    public void execute(Packet p) {
        size = (int)p.readByte();
        context.pixmapArray = new Pixmap[size]; //create Pixmap array with number of maps
        int i=0;
        while(i<size) {
            context.getMaps().add((String)p.readByteString()); //writes all map names to list
            Integer fileSize = p.readInt(); //read size of png
            if(fileSize == 0) {//incase image not found from server
                context.pixmapArray[i] = null;
            }else {
                Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(p.readBytes(fileSize), 0, fileSize); //byte[] to pixmap
                context.pixmapArray[i] = pixmap; //add pixmap to pixmap array for future use
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

readBytes method:

```
    public byte[] readBytes(int length) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
        this.dataBuffer.readBytes(bytes); //netty ByteBuf 

        return bytes;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are re-encoding the image, and thus changing the file size. When you read the image `ImageIO.read()` it may lose metadata, then when you write it with `ImageIO.write()` it is not guaranteed to encode it byte for byte the exact same as it was initially encoded on disk. I'd recommend just copying the bytes directly from the file:

```
File imageFile = new File(mapDir);
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(imageFile.toPath());
writeInt((int)imageFile.length()); //this should be the same as fileContent.length
writeBytes(fileContent);
```